# Mensagem do Tomcat com JSF erro 403

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat

Estou usando o **netBeans 8.1** para desenvolver uma aplicação em JSF, porém quando executo a página de **facelets template** aparece a mensagem que estou postando no fórum.

Meu **tomcat** foi **instalado** junto **com o netbeans**, e já pesquisei em alguns fóruns me instruíram a trocar o tipo de administrador que o tomcat estava usando. Já coloquei como **manager-gui**, **manager-script** e nada resolveu.

Alguém poderia me auxiliar com este erro?

[image: Imagem aqui]

Estrutura do projeto
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Arquivo `web.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <display-name>semeru_jsf_maven</display-name>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <!--        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>-->
    </welcome-file-list>

    <!-- Duração da sessão -->

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>

        <!-- Configurações do tema do PrimeFaces -->
    <context-param>  
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>  
        <param-value>sam</param-value>  
    </context-param>       

        <!-- Configurações do JavaServer Faces -->

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- SOLUÇAO foi tirar o bloqueador de xhtml
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>Bloqueia o browser de acessar arquivos xhtml</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>xhtml files</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint/>
    </security-constraint> -->

    <!-- Configurações do PrimeFaces -->

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.primefaces.resource.ResourceServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/primefaces_resource/
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Arquivo `faces-config.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
              version="2.0">

    <lifecycle>
        <phase-listener>br.com.semeru.util.PhaseListenerSemeru</phase-listener>
    </lifecycle>

</faces-config>
```

Comment: Pode postar uma screenshot da estrutura do seu projeto? O contexto da url esta setado?

Comment: Douglas esta ae a estrutura do projeto, qual contexto de url vc se refere?

Comment: Era para verificar, nesse caso provavelmente é o /JSF/ na barra de endereço, na qual vem logo após o ip:porta. Qualquer outro recurso dentro da pasta resources, como CSS é lido sem problemas? Você tem alguma configuração no web.xml ou em qualquer outro arquivo, correspondendo o caminho das paginas? Paginas fora da pasta resource, são acessadas normalmente?

Comment: Como está seu `faces-config`? Como está seu `web.xml`?

Comment: Douglas, Bruno coloquei os códigos dos dois arquivos, para voces analisarem. Obrigado Pela Ajuda!

Comment: Você tem uma *security constraint*  que bloqueia o acesso diretamente ao XHTML, já tentou algo como `localthos:8084/JSF/resources/main.faces`? Outra coisa, o `web.xml` postado está errado, não está fechando um `url-pattern` de um `servlet-mapping`.

Comment: Bruno muito obrigado era a restriçao de segurança!

Comment: Michell, que bom que resolveu o problema. Poderia postar a solução encontrada como resposta logo abaixo? assim, pode ser que sirva pra alguem futuramente.

Comment: Eu comentei a restriçao que bloqueava o acesso ao xhtml!

Comment: @MichellXexeu  publique a resposta e marque com aceita, assim você pode ajudar outras pessoas.